# Rails: Form Validation Errors Are Not Showing (with Formtastic and Bootstrap-Sass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, formtastic

I'm using Bootstrap-Sass along with Formstatic. I thought an error message should be automatically shown next to the field with Formstatic like in this picture: [image: here]
<sub>(source: [asciicasts.com](http://asciicasts.com/system/photos/227/original/E185I06.png))</sub>

But even if the user puts an invalid input, my app does not show an error message. This seems to be an easy problem but I cant figure out the reason behind.

**PostController**

```
# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.view = 0
  @post.like = 0 
  @post.hate = 0
  respond_to do |format| 
    if @post.save
      @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], order: 'like desc', per_page: 10) 
      format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**PostModel**

```
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true,
                      :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 300}
```

**_form (Post)**

```
<% @post = Post.new %>
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.semantic_errors :name %>
<%= f.inputs do %>
     <%= f.input :name, :label => 'name' %>
     <%= f.input :content, :label => 'body' %>
<% end %>
<%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :button_html => { :class => "btn btn-primary" }, :as => :button  %>
    <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
<% end %>
```

In PostController, I tried deleting the following two lines

```
    #format.html { render action: "new" }
    #format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

and added

```
render @post.errors
```

Then, I got

```
@messages={:name=>["can't be blank"], :content=>["can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"]}>
```

So I think the problem might be the way I'm rendering json is wrong. Could someone help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Rails has its own rendering for validation errors, which doesn’t match the HTML structure or the CSS structure used by Bootstrap.

To solve this porblem you can just add to view your own code block for output errors.

```
<% if @posts and @posts.errors and @posts.errors.count > 0 %>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
   <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;<a>
   <strong><%= pluralize(@posts.errors.count,"error") %> validation problems found.</strong>
   <ul>
   <% @posts.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
     <li><%= error %></li>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Or you can move this block to partial template to avoid dublication of code.

```
<% if resource and resource.errors and resource.errors.count > 0 %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;<a>
    <strong><%= pluralize(resource.errors.count,"error") %> validation problems found.</strong>
    <ul>
    <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
      <li><%= error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And pass @posts to parameters

```
<%= render "shared/validation_errors", :resource => @posts %>
```

Here you can find more information about this problem
http://fizzylogic.nl/2013/12/22/temp-slug-54/